# $\arctan$ relation

Tags: trigonometry

Once again, I apologize because I'm too lazy to try a comphensive post.
I am at a loss to understand why this conclusion is etablished in this paper as show here [image: here].

As far as I know

[image: trig^{-1}]

But what argument can be conclude the final result.

Comment: From (2.40), $\frac{\sin\theta(\tau)}{\cos\theta(\tau)}=\tan(\theta(\tau))=-\psi(\tau)/\phi (\tau)$, right?

Comment: But what about the other relations!

Comment: Are you talking about all the relations in (2.41)? Observe that you need to be careful when inverting a relation of the type $y=\tan(x)$. The result is not simply $x=\arctan(y)$ (this will only produce a value $x$ between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions